# How to open mailto links in new tab using on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I need to open href mailto links in new tab on firefox. I tried target _blank it doesn't help me.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried? The Operating system of the user usually decides how to handle mailto links, you cannot change that behavior using an HTML attribute as far as I know.

Comment: <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in Firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646552

Comment: They have put this bug on the back burner due to nobody to work on it. Sad to say after being reported 8 years ago it will likely never be fixed. If anyone comes up with a workaround, It would be great to post it on this question since it comes up at the top of google results.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to open web-mail client for this. But, this won't be a *href mailto* link.

Check this similar thread [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576255/how-to-open-mailto-links-in-new-tab-for-users-that-have-gmail-as-the-default-mai)

Comment: Will popup blockers block window.open() ?

Comment: well, there is a chance, but not too sure about the behaviour :(