# mailto link to compose in existing gmail tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, gmail, mailto

Using a `mailto:` link or Javascript is it possible to get Chrome to launch the compose new email window in the tab where Gmail is already open, rather than opening another Gmail "instance"? `mailto:`, `window.location.href` or `window.open(url)` don't do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think - well I hope not - that is is possible to change the URL of a window not opened by yourself, or rather your code.

If you have that you can use [window.open(url, `name`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) where `name` is a unique string you set for for window

See an example for its use in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576255/how-to-open-mailto-links-in-new-tab-for-users-that-have-gmail-as-the-default-mai/22329030#22329030)

In some browsers setting `target` to a unique name also works for `mailto` URLs, but it's not guaranteed, and it's very annoying for people who do not use webmail.