# mailto links are not opening in a new tab for firefox

Tags: javascript, tabs, mailto

mailto links are not opening in a new tab for firefox. It is working perfect for all other browsers, but unfortunately I couldn't able to open in a tab in firefox, so that my application is get redirected to mail clients like google/yahoo etc. Is there any work-around for this issue? I have tried the following code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="mailto:?subject=subjectText&body= bodyText">email</a>
```

Comment: ?? `mailto:` links are supposed to open the user's chosen mail agent. You can't control what that is.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mailto:` link will open the outlook application or the thunderbird application or any other mail agent you use. It won't open a website for you.

According to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

*Though its use is not strictly defined, URLs of this form are intended to be used to open the new message window of the user's email client when the URL is activated*

and

*The software mechanism activated by the link requires that a default email client be established on the computer*

There is some information which seems to allow gmail as default agent in chrome though. Read this question:

[How to open mailto links in new tab for users that have gmail as the default mail handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576255/how-to-open-mailto-links-in-new-tab-for-users-that-have-gmail-as-the-default-mai)

Comment: Suppose if there is no mail client app installed in the user machine, it would ask for gmail/yahoo mail clients to open in browser, then it should open in a new tab right?

Comment: I added a link to the comment which is some what the same question and some what not, but maybe it helps you