# Opened added mailto:sales@abc.com in anchor tag. in new tab

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have added mailto:sales@abc.com in anchor tag. when user click on link then the mail ***application is get opened in current tab***. But I want the mail ***tab should be opened in new tab.***

Please suggest me solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open mailto links in new tab for users that have gmail as the default mail handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576255/how-to-open-mailto-links-in-new-tab-for-users-that-have-gmail-as-the-default-mai)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

```
<a href="mailto:sales@abc.com" target = "_blank">Click me</a>
```

Comment: It must work. Better, Paste your line of code here. So that we can see the problem.

Comment: <a href="mailto:sales@abc.com" target="_blank" ><img src="images/email.png" alt="" /> sales@abc.com</a>