# How to add custom gmail recipient from mailto

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got that link:

```
window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=150b0f7ffb682642&to=mailto");
```

It's changeing my default mailto link to gmail link. 
Let's say  I've got:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com"></a>
```

And after javascript this a link is

```
window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=150b0f7ffb682642&to=mailto");
```

Is it possible to force gmail to use recipient from mailto?

Comment: How is mailto turning into window.open? Is this a link in an email or a webpage?

Comment: @epascarello I mean I've got class on this a link that after function start and link is clicked change it to gmail link.

Is this some kind of answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576255/how-to-open-mailto-links-in-new-tab-for-users-that-have-gmail-as-the-default-mai/22329030#22329030 ?

Comment: Why? Why not allow people to use their own mail apps?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - client want me to do this.