# Cannot open page in a new tab using location.href

Tags: javascript

I need to use window.location.href to open the user's email so for that I have the following code:

```
$("#email").click(function(){
      window.location.href = "mailto:myemail.com?subject=Subject&body=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

});
```

Which works fine. However, the problem is I cannot open the user email page in a new tab and it opens by redirecting the current page which is not user friendly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "user email page"? The user might have an email program that opens outside the browser (e.g., Outlook). Why don't you just have `<a href="mailto:...">Email</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `target="_blank"` attribute on any regular anchor tag to make sure that the link is opened in a new tab, without using any JavaScript. Note, however, that `mailto` links are often handled by browsers specially and may just redirect to the system's default mail app without opening a visible tab.

```
<a id="email" target="_blank" href="mailto:person@example.com?subject=Subject&body=Body">
  Email us!
</a>
```

---

Edit: It looks as if this method won't work in certain versions of Firefox, due to a bug. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24924745/7256039).)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `window.open()`

**Example**:

`window.open("mailto:myemail.com?subject=Subject&body=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");`

Comment: it does not open the email page that way

Comment: But using location.href I am able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
[Open the href mailto link in new tab / window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549816/open-the-href-mailto-link-in-new-tab-window)

You can't open a 'mailto' link in new tab/window by default.

You need to use `window.open()` in your click override.

Answer (score 0):

please check below link and you can view the demo using this link.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open